# Is it possible to use an ARM DStream debugger with IAR

Tags: arm, iar

I was wondering if it is possible to use an ARM DStream debugger from with IAR Embedded Workbench?

Comment: I don't see DStream mentioned in my installation, but it could be compatible with different name or there could be third party driver. I think it would be best if you would contact IAR and/or DStream provider directly and ask.

Comment: @user694733 I know it's not directly supported and can't find anything on the web. I was hoping there was a sneaky way to use it. Failing that is there any way to use J-Link to debug a Renesas R-Car H3 Cortex-R7 Core?